# How can I control a DSLR camera programmatically over Wi-Fi?

Tags: canon, tethering, wireless, wifi, programming

I'm a programmer and writing an application in C# (Windows 7) which should take pictures (and also download them) via Wi-Fi.
I can't use USB because the camera is about 50 meters away and mounted at a height of 3 meters.

Does anyone know a SDK, API or library to connect to a Canon camera via Wi-Fi?
Or any other information how this could be solved?

The camera is a Canon 70D.

Comment: The way I do it: TV USB stick with WiFi, Linux, gphoto2, and web server (you can use different protocols, not just http; for file transfer I use sftp) on the stick. Works with all my Nikons and Canons. List of supported cameras is at http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php

Comment: @IliahBorg what's a "TV USB stick"?

Comment: @JDługosz It is a microcomputer $40 t0 $100, slightly larger than a normal USB flash drive memory stick, it has an HDMI connector, WiFi, USB for keyboard/mouse/camera control, and usually a slot for a microSD card. I use GK802 http://www.stickcomputing.com/zealz-gk802/ - but now there are better choices. When chosing, make sure it runs Linux (verify with forums that it does).

Comment: You may want to get a look at https://www.didp.canon-europa.com No idea whether the SDK works over Wi-Fi or along via USB, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about programming rather than photography.  Also examples of the uses of the canon sdk in c# are widely available from search engines.

Comment: @JamesSnell It is about programming as a means to accomplish doing photography.

Comment: @MichaelClark - The help center specifically says Programming is off-topic here.  As both a programmer and a photographer I read the question as one of finding and implementing an API which is a problem purely in the programming domain.  I welcome a suggestion in meta for a clear policy that allows us to accept photographic software development questions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in this project, http://dslrdashboard.info/.

It takes a TPLINK MR3040 (~$30.00, and looks *awfully* similar to the camranger!) and provides a dd-wrt firmware image that puts some kind of API onto the device that DSLR Dashboard uses.  DSLR Dashboard appears to be available as a PC app, as well as IOS and Android.

I recently bought a device, changed the firmware, and tried it out with an iPad.

I don't know if the API is "open" (i.e., defined well enough for 3rd parties), but the source code is on github: https://github.com/hubaiz

The apps themselves might be good enough for what you need as well!