# How can I tether multiple Canon cameras over wifi to one computer?

Tags: canon, tethering, wireless

We do event photography coverage also. so we have to do instant printing. normally we do removing camera's chips and copy pictures and print it. That is very difficult thing and time wasting.

So I try to connect all the cameras as the picture attached. I could connect only one camera because **Canon's EOS Utility** can manage One Camera. so how can I connect other cameras for that.

I appreciate if someone can give a solution for this.

[image]

Comment: The answers to this [question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20299/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-transfer-photos-from-a-dslr-to-a-pc-hard-disk-as?rq=1) might answer your problem also.

Answer (score 2):

Certain Eye-Fi SD cards can achieve this to a degree. It looks like the Pro X2 cards might be required and you may only be able to transfer one at a time, but that may not matter to you.

As noted in the [Pro X2 specs](https://mobihelp.eyefi.com/hc/en-us/articles/204131934):

> **Infrastructure Support:** Transfer photos from multiple Mobi Pro cards
>   directly over configured wireless networks without disrupting your
>   internet connections

See this discussion for more information about using an Eye-Fi in this way: https://community.eyefi.com/eyefi/topics/can-2-cameras-using-eyefi-connect-wirelessly-to-a-single-computer

Also note that you won't be able to use the Canon software(Camera Connect; EOS Remote was discontinued) for this unless you are the first known to hack it to do such a thing.

Comment: Why do you say EOS Utility has been discontinued? Canon still releases updates of EOS Utility for all of my EOS DSLRs. If you check the support page for the 6D (shown in the illustration in the question), the latest version of EOS Utility listed for Windows 10 is ver. 3.7.0 released 8/30/2017. For Max OS High Sierra v.10.13 the most recent release is EOS Utility ver. 3.7.0 released 12/18/17.

Comment: Perhaps that could be clarified in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question here:  https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/72846/20519

> You may be interested in this project, http://dslrdashboard.info/.
>
> It takes a TPLINK MR3040 (which looks awfully similar to the
>   camranger!) and provides a dd-wrt firmware image that puts some kind
>   of API onto the device that DSLR Dashboard uses. DSLR Dashboard
>   appears to be available as a PC app, as well as IOS and Android.
>
> I recently bought a device, changed the firmware, and tried it out
>   with an iPad.
>   [...]